# java: Check if server has a specific file?

Tags: java, file

i have a server sending a requested file (from a client) to a client. Want i want to do is if the file does not exist on the server side print out and error on both ends.

For example, client requests blahblahblah.txt from server but server doesn't have it. Server would print "error. does not exist" but also the client will print on its side "error. does not exist".

My file transfer works perfectly but it'd be great if there's a way to handle this error. If a bad input is typed in the server handles it well with the if statement but then the client just waits for a file (which makes sense because nothing is being sent). Right now i have, on the server side,

```
File f = new File("....");
if (!f.exists()) 
{
  System.out.println("error. does not exist");
}

else
{
  (send file)
}
```

Not sure how to handle this on the client side. Any help would be great.

Comment: To be able to give an answer we need to know how the (send file) task is implemented.

Comment: basically, the server searches for the file that's requested. It'll then read it into a byte array and eventually send it over a socket via a bufferedoutputstream.write()

Comment: if you only transfer the content of the file then there is no way to transfer something like a status. So you will have to change the transfer of your file or add another extra transfer for the status. I would suggest using something less "low-level" for your problem. If you use some exiting protocol/library then that handles all this status stuff for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give a syntax to your response, where first 3 bytes always represent "status code".  If the file was successfully found, the first 3 bytes will be 001 and then rest of the bytes will be the actual file.

If the file couldn't be found the first 3 bytes will be 900 and there will be no other bytes in the response after that.

This way, the server always writes something back to the client (file not found, and also for an unexpected errors during File reading).

Comment: I'm just curious. Why did you choose 900 to tell that the file is not found ? is it a convention ?

Comment: I don't know about convention.. but it allows us to say things like "900-999" range is meant for error codes.

Comment: Ok great idea. It's like a convention. I love it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea for you.
What you could do, is to create a class which has two attributes, an first one of the type File and a second one of the Type boolean. When the file exists, you do myObeject.setFile(f) and smyObject.setFound(true). You send the object to the client who will see that recievedObject.getFound() equals true so he will do recievedObject.getFile() and get the file. Otherwise, if the file is not found, you do myObeject.setFile(null) and smyObject.setFound(false) and send myObject. When the client will recieve the object, he will check for the value of the boolean and discover that it equals false. He will then show the error message instead of doing getFile. +1 if you like :D

Comment: Writing an object back to a stream is bigger challenge than just writing a file's contents. When an object is written to a stream, then we have to really be sure that the client can create an Object in its own memory using those bytes. Example:  A Java Server can't just send a Object to a C# Client without using special protocol/libraries.